# .htacces cache control for AJAX requests

Tags: ajax, apache, caching, .htaccess, cache-control

I have a page on my website that makes AJAX GET requests when a user clicks a button, for example the url to be gotten will look like:

```
/php/getData.php?field1=val1&field2=val2
```

The value returned by `getData.php` with these two values will not change (at least for a few months) so how can I implement cache control in my .htaccess file to tell the browser to cache the result for a certain amount of time?

For example, I tell the browser to cache js and css file in the following way:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=3024000, must-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

^ this sets the cache-control header for 30 days.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no directive in Apache to match against a query-string. Just filenames and directories.

Comment: Are you sure, you can do this with ReWriteRule

Comment: But you won't be able to control the cache headers with a rewrite rule. It only rewrites your URL, but will send the rewritten one (in your case `/php/getData.php?field1=val1&field2=val2`) to Apache.